# Convert float NaN to 0

Tags: arraylist, floating-point

I want to write out a set of probabilities. It turns out that in some cases, I end up dividing by zero, which leads to a probability of NaN. For example, if "success" and "trial" are Arraylists, then

```
float prob = (success.size()*1f)/(trial.size());
System.out.println(prob);
```

will return "NaN" if "trial.size()" is 0. In that case I'd like prob to equal 0, not "NaN". The zero can be an integer, a String, I don't care.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Although you can certainly do that replacement, I would also take another look at the logic of what you are doing. In a probability context a NaN due to 0/0 division often means you have no information at all about the probability, not that you know it to be zero.

Comment: Thats true. But I'm using this formula as a small part of a large model of cell metabolism. In my case, no information does mean 0 "prob" for all practical purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
trialSize = trial.size(); 
float prob = 0; 
if (trialSize != 0){
    prob = (success.size()*1f)/(trialSize);
}
System.out.println(prob);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just check for a NaN and set it to 0. What's so hard about that? One simple way to check for NaNs is to compare a number with itself, though using isNaN is probably cleaner.

```
float prob = (success.size()*1f)/(trial.size());
prob = (prob == prob) ? prob : 0.0f;
System.out.println(prob);
```

Comment: Best answer - value == value is an odd test to see fail, but it's easier than remembering Float.isNan? or whatever it is, and works if for some reason the result is a Fixnum

Answer (score 1):

Just check it.  Avoid division by zero.

```
float prob = 0;
if( trial.size() > 0 ) prob = (float) success.size() / trial.size();
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe if you use an if statement

```
if result == NaN
  return 0
end
```

Comment: The `result == NaN` test will always evaluate to false, either because result is not a NaN, or because it is a NaN and therefore is not equal to anything, itself included.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan in Ruby, at least, NaN can be checked with .nan? method from Float class.

Comment: In most languages there is some library call that will test for NaN. If not, there is always `result != result`. Anything other than a NaN is equal to itself.